# $scope variables vs var

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

in ngTable documentation, example 1 (http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1)

There's this line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

In the js file, he has

```
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
....
];
```

What specifically does $data do?  I would normally do

```
$scope.data = [...];
```

and then

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in data">
```

Interestingly enough, when I create a second one, it doesn't work.  e.g.

```
var data2 = [...];
```

and in HTML

```
{{$data2.length}}
```

This prints nothing.  Can someone clarify this for me?  Thanks!

Comment: What matters is tableParams, which gets the table data from the data array passed i its constructor. Read the code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example `data` is indeed only local and cannot be used directly. The example works because of the use of `data` in the `getData` function of the `$scope.tableParams` variable (code line 21):

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {
    total: data.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
  // note the variable ^^^^
    }
});
```

More information about this configuration can be found in [the documentation](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/wiki/Configuring-your-table-with-ngTableParams#getdata).